# How to display only image from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

***Hello,***

I have a React app and I'm fetching the Blogger API using axios. In the response, there is a `content` property. It contains HTML, but in string like this:

```
   {
       "content": "<div> some content </div>"
   }
```

So I'm using `react-html-parser` package to convert it to JSX.

The problem is, I want to take the first `<img/>` from this `content` JSX and display only it - hide other elements.

---

I tried set `display: none` for `*` and `display: block` for `img`, but then nothing was visible - including image.

---

---

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first extract the image tag as string and then display it via `react-html-parser`

Try this

```
let imageTagStr = content.match(/<img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>/i);
```

Comment: great! please, just accept one answer for this question to be considered "closed". thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by firstly editing the string to isolate the  tag:

```
const firstSplit = content.split('<img')[1].split('/>')[0].concat('/>');
const finalsplit = '<img'.concat(firstSplit);
```

**What is this doing?**

1. Split the string where the `<img` tag starts and grab the second part of that split
2. Split it again where it ends and grab the first part of that string
3. Add to the string `/>` because that was split by step two
4. Add `<img` to the front of the firstSplit because that was split in step one

**OR**

Using regex and .match you can do something like this:

```
content.match(/<img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a React problem.
Why not try to turn your html string into Dom elements using :

```
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(YOUR_STRING, "text/xml");
```

And then parse it using just javascript.